# Why does this code declare a DISTINCT type?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, static-typing

ShlObj.pas line 9922 (as in Delphi XE):

```
type
  BFFCALLBACK = function(Wnd: HWND; uMsg: UINT; lParam, lpData: LPARAM): Integer stdcall;
  TFNBFFCallBack = type BFFCALLBACK;
  {$EXTERNALSYM BFFCALLBACK}
```

---

Answering to David Heffernan's comment here because i think this outlines a relevant background for possible *why do you ask this?* question.
Procedural types for callback routines of Windows API origin are declared as type aliases (you know, canonical API name + "Pascalised" alias, or vice versa sometimes). Examples are `Windows.PIMAGE_TLS_CALLBACK`, `ShlObj.LPFNDFMCALLBACK` et cetera. Type declaration shown above is an exception. Thats why i'm asking :-)

Comment: Please suggest a proper tag(s) for such subtle matter as Pascalish type-identity.

Comment: I'd say delphi plus delphi-xe tags are fine. I doubt any other tags would ever help anyone much.

Comment: Do you see the use of distinct types anywhere else in that unit? Or in Windows.pas? Makes a change from FARPROC I suppose!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, good question! I've added a reply to your comment to the question body.

Comment: Even more weird `stdcall` is not preceded by `;`. Never known it compiles.

Comment: @Serg, not really weird, directive modifies symbol declaration and belongs to it (as with absolute and hint directives) Too bad this rule is not strict.

Comment: @user539484 This sort of syntax (stdcall, warning/hint etc.) would work really well as an attribute in my view

Comment: Serg's deleted answer appears to be correct. So far as I can discern, it makes no observable different, for a function/procedure type, whether or not a distinct type is declared. In other words, if the code had been `TFNBFFCallBack = BFFCALLBACK` instead, that code would be functionally identical.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Deleted answer is wrong because you can pass procedural type as `var`. I never done it before, but it is possible and `type` prefix has same effect on procedural type as on other types.

Comment: You've reverted my title change twice. Why? Your title doesn't really tell the reader much about what the question is about. People can't see the code when they're reading the title in search results, so a reference to "this" code doesn't help. Instead, my title tells readers that the question is about function-pointer types, and I think mentioning aliases helps give more context to the term "distinct type."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a way to force us programmers to use TFNBFFCallBack instead of BFFCALLBACK. If it was an alias we could use either for the browse info structure. On a different platform TFNBFFCallBack could point to something different than BFFCALLBACK.